# Wincache Magento Setup

Tags: magento-1.8, cache, windows

Im currently running magento on a windows server, I have installed and configured wincache, I added the following to my `local.xml` file.

```
 <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    <cache>
        <backend>Zend_Cache_Backend_WinCache</backend>
        <prefix>file</prefix>
    </cache>
```

None of the files are caching within wincache though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your app/etc/local.xml file and add these lines in the section:

```
<cache>
     <backend>Zend_Cache_Backend_WinCache</backend>
     <slow_backend>file</slow_backend>
</cache>
```

Do the same steps as described above or here: [Magento LAMP vs WIMP: Running Magento with IIS and WinCache](http://www.rapidcommerce.eu/blog/2012/05/magento-lamp-vs-wimp-running-magento-with-iis-and-wincache/)

> After saving your local.xml file be sure to flush Magento’s cache; System -> Cache management -> Select all -> Refresh -> Submit. When you check your wincache.php file again entries should show up under both “User cache” and “Opcode cache”.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following post & make sure that your installation & configuration thereof is correct.

[Magento LAMP vs WIMP: Running Magento with IIS and WinCache](http://www.rapidcommerce.eu/blog/2012/05/magento-lamp-vs-wimp-running-magento-with-iis-and-wincache/)

It's specifically important to note:

> Edit your app/etc/local.xml file and add these lines in the section;

```
 Zend_Cache_Backend_WinCache
 file
```

> After saving your local.xml file be sure to flush Magento’s cache; System -> Cache management -> Select all -> Refresh -> Submit. When you check your wincache.php file again entries should show up under both “User cache” and “Opcode cache”.

Let me know if this helps you resolve things.

Comment: Well, I did do that. See <backend> and <prefix>.